# Google Analytics Users but no Pageviews?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-client

I'm using a custom dimension to view metrics by a page ID.

If I query metrics `ga:users` and `ga:pageviews` using my dimension `ga:dimension3` I'll get something like 20 users and 0 pageviews.

I think this is because a `user` gets counted regardless of which page they visit — but it makes this metric meaningless if I'm trying to understand metrics for a specific page.

How can I query useful metrics for a single page? Are there other metrics I should be looking at? Or perhaps a different way to form the query to return more relevant per-page metrics?

[image]

**Update**

I'm using gtag.js and my dimension has a scope of `hit`. Here's what I'm sending:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);} 

gtag('js', new Date()); 
gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-1', {"custom_map":{"dimension3":"pageid"}}); 
gtag('event', 'pageid_event', { 'pageid': 123 });
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I thought `config` was enough to send a pageview, but the docs make it sound like I need an event too.

Comment: What is the scope of custom dimension and when you send dimension1 to Google Analytics?

Comment: The custom dimension is a page ID and it's sent anytime a page is loaded. I'm using it with ga:nthDay to view metrics for each day of the last week.

Comment: If you query only ga:pageviews and ga:dimension1 what you obtain?

Comment: @MichelePisani I still get 0 pageviews if I only query ga:pageviews. But if I only query ga:users, I get a range of values.

Comment: Attach a screenshot of your custom dimension configuration and how you pass it to Analytics from the page, pls.

Comment: @MichelePisani I've been using the Query Explorer to experiment. See added screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is firing after the pageview and the custom dimension is associated with the event, not the pageview.

To to send custom dimension in this way:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_TRACKING_ID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID',{
  "dimension13": "123"
});
</script>
```

Then create a custom report using a flat table, like those in your screenshot.

Comment: Posted more details. I'm using gtag.js and docs seem to suggest that an event is needed too?

Comment: I modified my answer, try to see it.

Comment: The docs say `'custom_map': {'dimension<Index>': 'dimension_name'}` and not `dimension_value` which is confusing to me. But I'm gonna try what you suggest: remove the event and use the `dimension_value` in the config instead of `dimension_name`

Comment: I was having trouble because I was trying to use the format `{'custom_map': {'dimension<Index>':  'dimension_value'}}`, but I had to remove the `custom_map` object and use only `{'dimension<Index>':' dimension_value'}`

Comment: Yes, they are 2 different things, not necessarily wrong. In your case, using the event with custom dimension with hit scope was not what you needed to get the desired result.